# Wordpress Rest API returns error 500 but displays result

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have this snippet in my wordpress website. It returns the value but when I checked the http status it return 500 internal server. I enabled WP_DEBUGGING but when I checked there is no logs being captured related to this one *(Logs working since there is other logs coming in)*

I did try updating all plugins and wordpress version.

Weird part is it returns my expected value but with 500 internal server error.

Any idea how to check or fix this?

```
function at_rest_testing_endpoint()
{
     $response = array(
    'status'  => 200,
    'message' => 'Test'
  );

  return new WP_REST_Response($response);
}

/**
 * at_rest_init
 */
function at_rest_init()
{
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    // route url: domain.com/wp-json/$namespace/$route
    $namespace = 'api-test/v2';
    $route     = 'testing';

    register_rest_route($namespace, $route, array(
        'methods'   => 'GET',
        'callback'  => 'at_rest_testing_endpoint'
    ));
}

add_action('rest_api_init', 'at_rest_init');
```

This is the response using POSTMAN
[image]